CAS customization - endpoints expose
I wish to upgrade Apereo CAS from 5.x to 7.x but there is a huge architecture change and the way the project is overlayed, i found documentation for everything except what i want.
I want to create controller in cas overlay project and expose it for external api calls with authentication and without authentication.
Please help.
How do i modify CAS 6.x and above in order to create my custom controllers and expose endpoints.
I tried by simply creating Rest Controller classes and exposed its endpoints, but getting  screen.error.page.authdenied
screen.error.page.permissiondenied
Also i Tried to create Spring SecurityConfiguration but nothing worked out

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Did you find a fix for this?
